# C++ Access Violation while Reading from File

Tags: c++, file, binary, destructor

Just starting out on C++.

I am getting access violation errors while reading from a binary file. Here are the classes involved:

```
class Staff { //base class
public:
    Staff() {}
    virtual ~Staff{}
}
```

One of the derived classes:

```
class Scheduler : public Staff {
public:
    Scheduler() {}
    //no destructor defined
}
```

And then in code that uses these classes:

```
ifstream in("Scheduler.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
Scheduler s;
in.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&s), sizeof(Scheduler));
```

The moment I hit the read statement, the access violation exception triggers, and VS2013 points to the virtual destructor in class Staff.

Is it because I didn't explicitly create a destructor in class Scheduler? Or is it caused by something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Scheduler` is not a trivially copyable class, you cannot read from or write it bytewise to a file like this.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable

> A trivially copyable class is a class that
>
> 1. Has no non-trivial copy constructors (**this also requires no virtual functions or virtual bases**)
> 2. Has no non-trivial move constructors
> 3. Has no non-trivial copy assignment operators
> 4. Has no non-trivial move assignment operators
> 5. Has a trivial destructor

You'll either have to remove the virtual destructor (which brings its own set of issues if you want to use `Staff` polymorphically), read and write to the file using a serialization library, or write your own serialization function, the canonical way would be something like `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Staff const&);`

Comment: I can write Scheduler objects to the file just fine though, it only occurs when reading

Comment: @user2990428 Undefined behavior doesn't necessarily mean your program will crash. The vtable for `Scheduler` is set at runtime, it's highly unlikely to be identical each time you run the program.